# Running hh_client on one file hangs forever

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I used the build instructions from this link 
[centos install docs](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Prebuilt-packages-on-Centos-6.5)

It seemed to install fine. I ran hhvm --version

`HipHop VM 3.5.0-dev+2014.12.11 (rel)
Compiler: heads/master-0-g546087bf1b0560c4a9e254fcad46a9212e42ccc2
Repo schema: cf1780b3cc3857e091e924935ae6267e9794de9c
Extension API: 20140829`

So following the bootstrapping docs I create a directory with 2 files (test.php and .hhconfig)

I added the following code to test.php

```
<?hh

function f(): int {
  return 'not an int';
}
f();
```

In this directory i run hh_client and the following message appears for a long time 20-30mins+. Is this normal? I tried using a docker container with hhvm already and installed and got the same behavior.

Comment: What is the message ?

Comment: It keeps saying hhserver still initializing. If it was just started this can take some time. Retrying... \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a known problem: can you do `killall -9 hh_server; export USER=$(logname)` before trying again? If that fixes it, you've hit an issue I just fixed this week in https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/53b4d9b1ad7ccf99ef7b80d5d673f1578c9791c8. That fix should be in the latest nightly build, so if you update your build, that might fix it too.

If not, it sounds like you've set it up correctly. Please file a bug at https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues and I'll work with you on looking into it. StackOverflow isn't really the right forum for debugging like this.

Comment: The first time running this i used a bare centos 6.5 container. Like you mentioned after setting the logname manually it seemed to work now. Thank you

Comment: Glad that worked. Updating your nightly build to anything dated today or later will also fix it without needing to set `$USER`, or use the 3.5 release when it comes out in a few weeks.